# PHP Prints everything after => (wamp)

Tags: php, wamp

I've got a really wierd problem on my hands...

When I try to require a class of mine everything after the use of `=>` gets printed to the page instead.
There's really no problem in the code, it worked previously when I initially developed it on a linux machine but now when I try to use it in wamp it doesnt...

So my best guess is that it's a wamp problem although `=>` works fine in other classes.

I'll paste the code where this occurs anyway.

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once('classname.class.php');
Classname::getInstance();
```

classname.class.php:

```
<? 

class Classname
{
    protected static $defSettings = array(
        'TITLE' => 'My site'
    );
    other code...
```

So when I load the page it prints out:

> 'My site' );other code...

And a fatal error: "Class 'Classname' not found in C:\wamp\www\site\index.php on line 4"

What on earth could cause this?

EDIT: solved. Stupid "typo" error.

Comment: Check the source of the page.  I'm willing to bet you'll see some PHP code in it besides that.  Perhaps even the whole included script, being parsed as HTML (and hiding everything between the `<` and `>`).

Comment: Thank you! this made me notice that I was using shorthand php tags "<?"... I can't believe I didn't see this before, I've never used those before and I've been doing this for like 5 years. Got to say I'm feeling kind of stupid now lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every PHP code block MUST be encased with `<?php ... ?>` code tags, even if you're using `include()` or `require()`.

Remember, there is no such thing as a "PHP script". There are only files that contain PHP code blocks. Without the `<?php ... ?>` tags, the PHP interpreter will NOT treat the text as code.

Comment: The closing `?>` is neither required nor recommended for included PHP.